# When two charged conductors touch, is the charge equally distributed?

Tags: electrostatics

I understand that if two charged bodies of the same size touch, they will each become equally charged.

[image]

What I am unsure about, is if these bodies are of different sizes (e.g. one is 10x the size of the other), will the charges equally distribute, but then overall the charge on the larger object will be bigger than the charge on the smaller object?

I have been trying to google an answer to this, but I am not having much luck. Perhaps I just have the wrong keywords and someone can point me in the right direction?

Thank you kindly

Comment: "Same Size" can be misleading. If they're the same surface area, but different geometries, things could get complicated, or the same volume but different surface area.

Comment: [When two spheres of equal charge make contact, why does the larger sphere gain more charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133304/104696) is a related question.

Answer (score 3):

As a result of comments made by @Pieter and @ThePhoton I have updated my answer realising that one cannot solve this problem assuming that one has two spherical capacitors of capacitance $4\pi\epsilon_0a$ and $4\pi\epsilon_0b$ where $a$ and $b$ are their radii resulting in sharing the charge in the ratio of their radii.
Note that in [Feynman Volume II Chapter 6 Section 11](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_06.html) that ratio of charge formula is derived (equation 6.35) with the spheres separated and connected with a wire.
He also notes *. . . we are interested only in an estimate . . . . .*

The solution to the problem is given in the paper [Electrostatics of two charged conducting spheres](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2138/05eeb99f6b0212fbc227d711bd4f4cae85eb.pdf) written by John Leckner.
In Section 4, *The repulsive force between two spheres that are or have been in contact*, he derives expressions for the charge on the two spheres and then an approximate expression for the ratio of the charge on two spheres of radius $a$ and radius $b$

$$\dfrac{Q_\rm b}{Q_\rm a} \approx \left(\dfrac {b^2}{ a^2}\right)\left(\dfrac {\pi^2}{6}\right)^\left ({\frac {a-b}{a+b}}\right )$$

He says that this expression is correct if $a=b$ and also when one radius is much bigger than the other.
The maximum error of $2.4\%$ occurs when one radius is four times the other.

Using this formula it is interesting to see how the simplistic theory $\dfrac{Q_\rm b}{Q_\rm a} = \dfrac b a$ compares with the more sophisticated theory.

$a=b$ gives $\dfrac{Q_\rm b}{Q_\rm a} = 1$
$2a=b$ gives $\dfrac{Q_\rm b}{Q_\rm a} \approx 3.4$
$5a=b$ leads to $\dfrac{Q_\rm b}{Q_\rm a} \approx 18$
$10 a = b$ gives $\dfrac{Q_\rm b}{Q_\rm a} \approx 67$

whereas the simple analysis that I first described results in the ratio of charges being $1,\, 2,\,5,\,10$ respectively.

---

So the answer to the OP's question is that the larger sphere has more charge on it than the smaller sphere and when the spheres have the same radius they have the same charge on them.

Comment: I am not entirely convinced, because when the spheres touch, the charge will not be equally distributed over the surfaces.

Comment: @Pieter, you agree that if they are reasonably good conductors, and they touch for a long enough time, they'll reach equal potentials, though, right?

Comment: @Pieter I tend to agree with you but my analysis possibly gives the right order of magnitude?

Comment: @ThePhoton If the spheres are conductors then even a momentary touch will probably produce an equality in the potentials of the two spheres.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, equal potential, but that means that the field in the nooks close to the contact point is almost zero. So there is no charge there. Of course the field and the surface charge on the other side of the small sphere is larger. But it is not obvious to me that the result is that the charges would divide in proportion to the radii. And that is what the OP wanted to know. Easiest way to check this answer might be a finite-element calculation.

Comment: @Pieter As a result of you comment I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton As a result of you comment I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: Great! I tried to think about it, also starting to make contact with a wire when far away. Then disconnecting them, bringing them closer together until really close. Obviously this would cost work. And I suspected that there should be a field between them, but I saw no way of calculating. And (like the OP), I had no idea on how to google this.